# Java calculate progress on UnZipping process

Tags: java, android, unzip

I'm using an Unzipping process that I want to calculate its progress, here is the code with the counter:

```
float counter;
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {

        String zipFile = Path + FileName;

        String unzipLocation = Path;

        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(zipFile);
        ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);

        ZipEntry ze = null;
        while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            counter++;
            if (ze.isDirectory()) {
                dirChecker(ze.getName());
            } else {
                FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(Path
                        + ze.getName());
                while ((length = zin.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    fout.write(buffer, 0, length);                  
                }
                publishProgress((int)((counter/747.0)*100));
                zin.closeEntry();
                fout.close();
            }

        }
        zin.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
    }

  @Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    mProgressDialog.setProgress(values[0]);
}
```

I have only 1 .zip file which contains exactly 747 files... that why I use the number 747.
The problem is that values[0] is always 0 .. Am I calculating the process right? How should I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the last published value from the progress:

```
mProgressDialog.setProgress(values[values.length - 1]);
```

Possible problems:

- It might be that the progress of unzipping is so fast (or the GUI updating is slow) that `values = [0, 1, .... 99]`
- Your progress dialog isn't set up correctly (`setMax` and `setMin`)